# How can I change the background color of divs dynamically (depending on an order-status in woocommerce)?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I try to give out three divs with three different colors and phrases (each for every order-status: completed(green), pending (red), processing (orange).

```
<div class="order-actions2">
<?php
    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    if($order_status=="completed") {
        echo "Thank you for the payment" . ' ';
        $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );
        ?> <style type=text/css>.order-actions2 {background-color: green;} </style><?php
    }
    elseif($order_status=="pending") {
        echo "Spending money is always a statement" . ' ';
        $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );
        ?> <style type=text/css>.order-actions2 {background-color: red;} </style><?php
    }
    elseif($order_status=="processing") {
        echo "Spending money is always a statement" . ' ';
        $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );
        ?> <style type=text/css>.order-actions2 {background-color: orange;} </style><?php
    }
    
    if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="order-action2-button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . ' ' . 'now' . '</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

At the moment every div shows up green. If I wrap every status in an own div, I need to open and close php all the time. This makes me unable to use elseif.
Maybe there is a solution with arrays or something I don't know, yet? Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind you need a specific question to ask that can be factually and completely answered, not an opinion or discussion topic. Can you adjust your question so it's clearly stated what the specific question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is a misunderstanding of how CSS/HTML works.

Take this example:

```html
<style>p { color: red; }</style>
<p>1</p>
<style>p { color: blue; }</style>
<p>2</p>
<style>p { color: green; }</style>
<p>3</p>
```

**Which colour is the 1st paragraph?**

I suspect you would answer red, but that would be incorrect. All paragraphs are green.

The disconnect is that `p { color: green; }` doesn't mean *"from here onwards paragraphs are green"*, it means *"**all** paragraphs on the page are green"*.

What's worse is these are inline style tags, which are very bad practice and completely unnecessary.

So instead, just add a HTML class that mentions the order status, and put rules in a CSS file to change the colours, e.g.

```html
<div class="order-actions2 order-status--complete">
```

```css
.order-status--complete {
    background-color: green;
}
```

In PHP you could do this:

```php
<div class="order-actions2 order-status--<?php echo esc_attr( $order->status ); ?>">
```

This removes the styling part of the code from PHP entirely, simplifying things significantly, and making it much nicer to work with.

Remember, CSS rules apply globally across the entire page. `.order-actions2 { ... }` refers to ***all*** elements that have `order-actions2` as a HTML class, regardless of where they appear on the page.

You might also be tempted to use the `style=""` attribute, which is also extremely very bad practice. Ignore anybody who suggests this solution.

Some extra notes:

1. That `$actions = ..` line is identical in every single case, just move it to the end and call it once just before the if check
2. There's no reason to append  `. ' '` just add the space in the first string
3. `sanitize_html_class` is not a substitute for `esc_attr`. We're escaping here, not sanitising, so it still has to be wrapped in `esc_attr`

Comment: I implemented it like you explained - it works great.
I have understood a new concept of dynamic classes in php.
Thank you!